# At what point should side-quests (memories/reflections of strength) be undertaken?

Tags: sekiro-shadows-die-twice

So, as in all SoulsBourne games, there is not definitive "point" that anything should be undertaken. You can play through the entire game without even levelling and dying, so it's more about skill than progression. The only addendum to this is key events and items that develop the story.

E.g. In bloodborne you cannot access Rom before fighting Amelia. You cannot fight Amelia (at the very least) until you kill the Cleric Beast, and Gascoigne. In Dark Souls 1, you need to have defeated O&S before you gain access to the Lord Soul Boss Fights, etc.

However, in Sekiro, you can gain access to  a Memory, before you even fight the first Boss (i.e. an encounter with an on-screen Health Bar). Without the basic levels of skill (i.e. the skill tree) or equipment, this would rely *heavily* on player ability to overcome certain boss fights. Such an example is the [Young Lord's Bell Charm](https://sekiroshadowsdietwice.wiki.fextralife.com/Young+Lord%27s+Bell+Charm), which opens up a memory of "That Night" in the Hirata Estate. The Mini Boss [Shinobi Hunter: Eshin of Misen](https://sekiroshadowsdietwice.wiki.fextralife.com/Shinobi+Hunter+Enshin+of+Misen) is difficult enough on his own, let alone surrounded by the multiple archers, and torch and axe-wielding soldiers. Having the Mikiri Counter is pretty much a necessity. From here, the boss fights only get harder (seemingly at an exponential rate) until you come up against Lady Butterfly, which in my experience, is twice as hard as the "Main storyline" boss [Gyoubu Masataka Oniwa](https://sekiroshadowsdietwice.wiki.fextralife.com/Gyoubu+Oniwa) (horse-riding warlord that drops the first "reflection of Strength" Challenge).

So, is there any "guides" as to when/in what order particular boss fights should be undertaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflections of Strength are completely separate from the main game and have no impact on it - there's no point at which they "should" be done except when you feel like it. They were added pretty late in the game's life cycle as a way for players to just fight the Bosses (including some harder versions) without going through yet another full NG cycle. You can see them as post-game content.

As for the rest, the best advice I can give you is to go back to a previous area and see if there's another path when you get stuck. Sekiro is quite a bit less open than, say Dark Souls 1 for instance, as there are several "chapters" in the story that are unlocked once certain bosses are beaten. The Hirata memory is the only "special" area of its kind, although you can later unlock an "expanded" version of it under some circumstances (not spoiling it here, but it's easy to look it up as it's related to one of the game's endings) Generally I'd recommend doing it after Gyoubu, but if you're finding Lady Butterfly too difficult there's no shame in going back to Ashina a bit and revisiting Hirata later.